# Set Visibility and Invisibility for Two Shapes in all of sheets in Workbook by VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I wanna set visibility and invisibility for two shapes at the same time by VBA.
I wrote this code:

```
Sub Set_Visible_Invisible()

Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
ws.ActiveSheet.Shapes("btn_S2_Pasive").Visible = False
ws.ActiveSheet.Shapes("btn_S2_Active").Visible = True
Next ws

End Sub
```

but it's work for only active sheet, not all of the sheets that the workbook has.

Any idea is welcome.

Comment: Could the `.ActiveSheet` maybe have something to do with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
Sub Set_Visible_Invisible()

Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
   ws.Shapes("btn_S2_Pasive").Visible = False
   ws.Shapes("btn_S2_Active").Visible = True
Next ws

End Sub
```

The key issue is not to double specify the worksheet.